# What is the best way to stream data in real time into Big Query (using Node)?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, cloudflare-workers

I want to stream HTTP requests into BigQuery, in real time (or near real time).

Ideally, I would like to use a tool that provides an endpoint to stream HTTP requests to and allows me to write simple Node such that:
1.  I can add the appropriate insertId so BigQuery can dedupe requests if necessary and
2.  I can batch the data so I don't send a single row at a time (which would result in unnecessary GCP costs)

I have tried using AWS Lambdas or Google Cloud Functions but the necessary setup for this problem on those platforms far exceeds the needs of the use case here.  I assume many developers have this same problem and there must be a better solution.

Comment: The recommended pattern for this is to go via Pub/Sub and Cloud Dataflow. So, it looks like: `streaming data -> Pub/Sub -> Cloud Dataflow -> BigQuery`

Comment: @grahampolley I see dataflow templates for pub/sub to bigquery so should add pub/sub bw dataflow and bigquery as represented in your stream flow representation?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are looking for a way to [stream HTTP requests to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) and also send them in batch to minimize Google Cloud Platform costs, you might want to take a look at the public documentation where this issue is explained. 
You can also find a Node.js [template](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery_table_insert_rows-nodejs) on how to perform the stream insert into BigQuery:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

/**
* TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
*/
// const projectId = "your-project-id";
// const datasetId = "my_dataset";
// const tableId = "my_table";
// const rows = [{name: "Tom", age: 30}, {name: "Jane", age: 32}];

// Creates a client
const bigquery = new BigQuery({
    projectId: projectId,
});

// Inserts data into a table
await bigquery
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .insert(rows);
console.log(`Inserted ${rows.length} rows`);
```

As for the batch part, the recommended ratio is to use 500 rows per request even though it can be up to 10,000. More information about that Quotas & Limits for streaming inserts can be found in the public [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts).

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of Cloud functions. With the help of cloud functions, you can create your own API in Node JS and then it can be used for Streaming data in BQ.

Target Architecture for STREAM will be like this:
Pubsub Subscriber (PUSH TYPE) -> Google Cloud Function -> Google Big Query

You can make use of this API in batch mode as well with the help of Cloud Composer (i.e. Apache Airflow) or Cloud Scheduler to schedule your API as per your requirements.

Target Architecture for BATCH will be like this:
Cloud Scheduler/Cloud Composer -> Google Cloud Function -> Google Big Query